# Testing "validates ..., format => with"

Tags: rspec, rspec-rails

I have a User model with this validation

```
validates :name, :lastname, :format => {:with => /^[a-zA-Z]+$/, :message => 'Only letters and spaces allowed.'}
```

I'm not sure how to properly test it.

I've done a function that returns a random string made by 10 chars from an array of a-zA-z chars.

```
def get_random_name
  "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".split('').shuffle[0..10].join
```

end
    end

and then I get a new name for each run of my specs.

I don't want to test that it uses some regexp, because then I would be testing the implementation and not the behavior, and I also don't want to test only one hardcoded case.

My questions are: Should I do that? Is it really needed? Is it better or useless? Do you know any better way to test that kind of validations?

EDIT: another question, what about generating invalid random names? is there a way to create random names that includes at least one char outside the allowed values? I can't hardcode an array of all invalid values to randomize it since it would be TOO big

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testing against random data is a common testing technique called [Fuzzing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzz_testing). I would look at using [FuzzBert's](https://github.com/emboss/FuzzBert) Generators to create true random binary data to test against.

Here is an example of some great random data that you would not want getting past your validations.

```
irb> require 'fuzzbert'
       => true
irb> test_string = FuzzBert::Generators.random_fixlen(10)[]
       => "S\x1EU1\x11HVY\x0E\xD0"
irb> puts test_string
     S▲U1◄HVY♫�
       => nil
```

**Random Is Good**

Because it is converting random binary bits to strings, you are going to get some really funky results to test against. That is a good thing! Not only will it test against using known symbols like ?, but also all kinds of combinations of valid and invalid characters.

**Random is sometimes valid**

There is a chance you will get valid data every now and then, although very unlikely. Also, the odds of getting valid data decrease the longer the random string you create is.

A first attempt to solve this problem could be to just append an invalid character to every output, but I wouldn't suggest it. For example, if you always append "!", then it would make your test equivalent to making sure the string doesn't have a "!" in it and not a true test of the full regex possibilities.

I would suggest testing your random strings against that same regex, if it *does* pass it, generate a different string to test with.

Finally, you could just ignore the rare chance that the random data is valid. If every once-in-a-while this particular rspec fails, look at what string it failed on, if it was a valid string, then just rerun.

**Test all the possibilities**

You will never be able to test all non-valid strings (unless you have a short maximum length), but by using Fuzz Testing you will be able to test against strings that contain a large variety of valid and invalid characters.

Comment: thanks, that fits what I need to do, I'll do that check against the regexp to be sure the random name is invalid, I don't want the test to fail on some cases because the test will be run automatically, I don't want to get false errors

Answer (score 8):

Checkout the open-source project Shoulda Matchers:
https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers

Edit: Sorry just noticed that `Paul Fioravanti` mentioned Shoulda also. However you don't need to use FactoryGirl to create instances of the model. Using `create` isn't necessary for a validation tests.

You can create unit tests directly on the model:

```
describe User, 'Validations' do
  it { should allow_value("Name").for(:name) }
  it { should_not allow_value("Inv4lid_").for(:name) }
end
```

Answer (score 4):

In order to test valid and invalid formats (I think a regex is fine to define a format to validate against), how about defining what you think valid and invalid names are in some helper utility methods that you could perhaps refine over time if necessary.  For example:

**spec/support/utilities.rb**

```
def valid_names
  %w[Homer bart LISA]
end

def invalid_names
  %w[BuRn$ 5M1+h3Rs♡]
end
```

Then, you could write tests for `:name` (and `:lastname`) using RSpec, [shoulda-matchers](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers), and [Factory Girl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl_rails) that look something like this:

**spec/models/user_spec.rb**

```
describe User do

  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

  # ...

  describe "validations" do
    context "for name, lastname" do
      context "when format is invalid" do
        invalid_names.each do |invalid_name|
          it { should_not allow_value(invalid_name).for(:name) }
          it { should_not allow_value(invalid_name).for(:lastname) }
        end
      end

      context "when format is valid" do
        valid_names.each do |valid_name|
          it { should allow_value(valid_name).for(:name) }
          it { should allow_value(valid_name).for(:lastname) }
        end
      end
      # ...
    end
    # ...
  end
  # ...
end
```

If you ever intend to internationalize your app in the future, just remember that not all the world's names conform to this format.

Comment: but that way I'll be testing just a few cases, I want to test as many cases as possible with the most generic approach (that's way I want to generate random names)

Comment: I think that just generating a random string the way you have which matches your regex doesn't pinpoint what you really need to test.  Your regex tests for a name with upper/lower case letters.  That means you need to test your valid cases, which would be a string of only lower, only upper, and a combination of both, and test your invalid cases with numbers, symbols, other characters in the strings.  If you really want to do random string generators, you'd need one for each of the cases that needs testing, and in my opinion that doesn't offer any more value than a static string.

Comment: The problem is, TDD tells to first do the test, then do only the needed code to pass the test. If I have 3 test cases (lower, upper, combined) I could hardcode the 3 values and the test would pass (I know it has no sense to do that, but I'm trying to think the TDD method to the extreme :P). There must be some way to make the test to make you come out with that regexp, not a test for the regexp, a test that make you use that regexp.